# PowerApps Flow: Trigger condition not working. The flow keeps firing

Tags: sharepoint, powerapps, power-automate

I have tables with monthly data, and I need to calculate row-level summations. I also need a column-level summation for all columns.

My columns are:

```
Project ID | Name | Budget Year | Total Amount | Sum Total | Jan | Feb | ... | Dec
```

'Total Amount' is a calculated column, but this doesn't provide me with the column-level total, so I have a 'Sum Total' currency column that I populate using a flow that gets triggered every time something gets created or modified.

To ensure I don't run into an infinite loop, I have the below in the Trigger Condition:

```
@not(equals(triggerBody()?['Total_x0020_Amount'], triggerBody()?['SumTotal']))
```

Alternatively, I also tried:

```
@not(equals(triggerOutputs()?['body/Total_x0020_Amount'], triggerOutputs()?['body/SumTotal']))
```

Neither of these work and my flow keeps firing. Could someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Could be a lot of things. **1st:** You'll want to be sure the column values are what you *think* they are. Insert a `Compose` action after the trigger. Set the field to the check column value. Insert another `Compose` action. Write an comparison expression to determine equality.

Comment: **2nd:** Check that `SumTotal` column name. Youre showing "Sum <space> Total" but trying "SumTotal". You may be missing the `x0020` between words. Try to ALWAYS name columns without spaces using [camelCase or UpperCamelCase](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Camel_case) to avoid these problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to fix this by having a Condition block that performs the update only when any of the specific monthly columns get updated. The flow still gets triggered on every edit, but this condition throttles the flow considerably and has been very reliable so far.

[image: Screenshot of the part of the flow that handles this.]

Answer (score 0):

Another way to approach this is to let the flow run, but check to see if the totals match the expected outcome **BEFORE** updating the record.

If they match, don't update the record, just skip over it.  If it doesn't add up correctly, update the record.

The next time the flow runs for that item, it will hit the first part of the logic and it will know that no update needs to occur.

Comment: Ok, so help me understand, are Total_x0020_Amount and SumTotal meant to equal the same thing?  Therefore, when you run your trigger condition, if they don't match, then you run the logic?

Comment: "Total Amount" being a calculated column doesn't allow me to have a column-level total at the bottom. That feature is available only for non-calculated (regular) columns, which "Sum Total" is.